# Searching in UItableview - Using Nested Array NSpredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nspredicate, multidimensional-array

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to displays my filtered search results on the UItableview .

My displays methods work very well ... but when I try to search for a specific data in my array  it only displays the `FIRST OBJECT OF THE SECTIONS` or crashes with this error message :

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]' ***

My array structure : `AllDataGroupbyServiceArray`

```
 (
    {
    Companies =         (
                    {
            AddressInformation = h3k2w3;
            Name = Teg;
            Service = "";
        }
    );
    Services = "";
},
    {
    Companies =         (
                    {
            AddressInformation = j9g2k6;
            Name = Megan;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2k2w3;
            Name = test;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2t3b3;
            Name = Janet;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = "J4J 1H7";
            Name = Rick;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = "H1T 4B6";
            Name = Herber;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = "J0K 3B0";
            Name = test;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2k2w3;
            Name = test;
            Service = Electrician;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2k2w3;
            Name = canada;
            Service = Electrician;
        }
    );
    Services = Electrician;
},
    {
    Companies =         (
                    {
            AddressInformation = J0L2K0;
            Name = "Colas Bn";
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = J5A1M2;
            Name = mrnoskill2;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = J0L2K0;
            Name = test8;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = J5C1S3;
            Name = test6;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = h3r1z2;
            Name = Jason;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = j7h2k7;
            Name = max;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = J5Z2W5;
            Name = Fred;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = "H4G 1K6";
            Name = Joe;
            Service = Mason;
        },
                    {
            AddressInformation = j3y7a6;
            Name = Tets;
            Service = Mason;
        }
    );
    Services = Mason;
},
    {
    Companies =         (
                    {
            AddressInformation = h2k2w3;
            Name = jake;
            Service = Plumber;
        }
    );
    Services = Plumber;
}
)
```

**Here's the filtering method :**

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
// Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
// Remove all objects from the filtered search array
[filteredObject removeAllObjects];
// Filter the array using NSPredicate


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K.%K CONTAINS[cd] %@",
                          @"Companies",@"Name",searchText];


filteredObject = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[AllDataGroupbyServiceArray  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}
```

**Number of line in sections code : works well but not with search**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

#warning Incomplete method implementation.

// Returns the number of items in the array associated with the letter for this section.



// Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and return the count from the appropriate array

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    NSArray *filterCount = [filteredObject valueForKey:@"Services" ];

   return [filterCount count];

} else {


 NSString* serviceSection = [publicServiceArray objectAtIndex:section];
 NSArray* arrayservicescount = (NSArray*)[ServicesDictionary objectForKey:serviceSection];
    return arrayservicescount.count;


}

}
```

**Table header : works well**

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {



     // Condition for the search tableview
       if( tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)




 {
   NSArray *sections = [NSArray array] ;

       sections = [ filteredObject valueForKey:@"Services"] ;

       return [ sections objectAtIndex:section] ;


   }




NSArray *sections = [NSArray array] ;

    sections =  [[myObject valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.Service"]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] ;

    return [sections objectAtIndex:section];



}
```

**Cell display issue : does not work for the search**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
          UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


 NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:AllDataGroupbyServiceArray.count];

//  set the search object from the appropriate array

// Condition for the search tableview
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    tmpDict = [[filteredObject valueForKey:@"Companies" ]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]


} else {

    tmpDict = [[[AllDataGroupbyServiceArray valueForKey:@"Companies" ] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;





}




NSMutableString *text;

text = [tmpDict valueForKey:name] ;


NSMutableString *detail;
detail =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Postal code : %@ ", [tmpDict valueForKey:serviceAddress]];

 // NSMutableString *images;
   // images = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
   //           [tmpDict objectForKey:serviceAddress]];
   //  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
   //  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    // UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];



cell.textLabel.text = text ;
cell.detailTextLabel.text= detail ;
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 70);


//   cell.imageView.image =img;

return cell;


}
```

I know I'm very close to the answer , but any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a problem in this line

you already have a filteredObject  with this line

```
filteredObject = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[AllDataGroupbyServiceArray  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

again you are filtering this array for Services key

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

NSArray *filterCount = [filteredObject valueForKey:@"Services" ];
```

*** you should return the filteredObject count ***

```
return [filterCount count];

 }
```

Comment: I change te array for [filteredObject count] now it gives me the following error : -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c85520
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9c85520'